# bootstrap - glyphicon glyphicon-ok and glyphicon glyphicon-remove not showing in IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, glyphicons

I have a bootstrap application and have integrated the glyphicon glyphicon-ok and glyphicon glyphicon-remove icons. It works fine with all browsers except older version of IE. I read some of the earlier comments that said there might be a bug, but not sure how to resolve this.

I have this over a popup for checking some conditions, it will display glyphicon-remove and glyphicon-ok based on the conditions being validated.

I checked some other posts and they said to to remove "Pragma: no-cache and/or Cache-Control no-store" from the header, but the server sends them and I could not control that. Is there anything else I can try from my side? It works in IE edge even.

```
<form:input class="form-control popupplacer" id="p1" path="cond1" placeholder="xxx" type="password" 
    data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus"
    data-content="<span id=&quot;x&quot; class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-ok&quot; style=&quot;color:#zzz;&quot;></span>"/>
```

Thanks.